# Github - Merging is blocked (confusing/misleading error message)

Tags: git, github, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I created a pull request, my approver requested some changes, i marked those resolved and clicked on `re-request` button with out seeing if the merging was blocked or unblocked. So now to unblock merging, do approver need to review the changes again and approve it ? Beacause the below message did not say it needs to be approved by reviewer.

> Merging can be performed automatically once the requested changes are
>   addressed.

[image: Merging is blocked]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you need to have your reviewer approve the changes.  Just because *you* think  you addressed the changes doesn't mean the reviewer agrees, and the only way GitHub can know that they've been addressed is to have the reviewer approve the changes.  They might disagree and request more changes.

Part of the reason this functionality exists is to provide an effective control, which is required in many regulated industries before code can be merged or deployed.  It wouldn't be very effective if the author could vouch for their own changes.

Comment: once i  resolve requested change, then is it mandatory to re-request reviewer to review again, or he will be notified automatically without the need of re-request

Comment: It's best to re-request review through the interface.  A reviewer is usually notified of updates you make, but at least I tend to ignore those since people often push lots of updates before they're ready for a re-review.

Comment: What happens when the developer who requested changes goes on vacation? This is what I'm currently dealing with.

Comment: This is exactly why the message "Merging can be performed automatically once the requested changes are addressed." is WRONG. No merging can be performed "automatically". No, you need a reviewer to review your additional change. There is nothing automatic about it. Come on GitHub, fix this message.

Comment: the reviewer "resolved the conversation" and still this isn't enough, github leaves us in the dark, can't merge, I may be interrupting a co-worker for no reason unless I understand what needs to be done

Comment: @ZoltanFedor "merging automatically" in this context means that you do not need to resolve merge conflicts. It has nothing to do with the requested changes.
If there are no pending changes requests, the prompt just say "Merging can be performed automatically."
The problem with the message is that it doesnt say who needs to adress the changes.

Answer (score 6):

Ideally it's best for the reviewer who requested changes to re-review.
But... if the original reviewer is unavailable then you can reach out to someone else who can review your changes & have them approve it instead.

---

[image: override requested-changes]

<sup>***This should be ofcourse used responsibly :)</sup>